# File uploading in Amazon S3 with Node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am using `aws-sdk` to upload files on Amazon S3. It is working fine and uploading files, but my problem is; it changed file name after uploaded to the server. For example, if I upload **sample.jpg**, and it renamed to something like **b4c743c8a2332525.jpg**. Here is my code.

```
AWS.config.update({ 
    accessKeyId: key, 
    secretAccessKey: secret
});

var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(path);

fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
});

fileStream.on('open', function () {
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    s3.putObject({
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: directory + file,
        Body: fileStream
    }, function (err) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        fs.unlinkSync(path);
    });
});
```

Is it normal to change file name after uploaded files to S3 server, or is there any options to upload the same file name? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither S3 nor the AWS SDK pick arbitrary file names for things you upload.  The names are set by your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `directory + file` when you set it as the S3 object key.  You may be uploading 'sample.jpg' from your browser (so the file is called *sample.jpg* locally on your disk), but the temporary file name that node.js uses to identify the file on it's disk may be using a hash like *b4c743c8a2332525.jpg*.